# Why is IIS 10 serving content using HTTP 1.1 instead of HTTP 2?

Tags: iis, asp.net, google-chrome, http2

I have a base install of IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016 which I have setup my basic web application on.

The application website uses HTTPS.

For some reason, when browsing from Chrome 63, the content is served using HTTP/1.1 when I expected it to be served over HTTP/2. I have checked the IIS logs which show:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-02-09 16:32:34
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-02-09 16:32:38 196.44.182.180 GET /uploaded/a87f9d27-3732-426f-80cb-ac531579a908.jpg - 443 - 196.44.177.71 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/63.0.3239.132+Safari/537.36 https://xxxxxxx/ 200 0 0 46
```

Interestingly, when I use https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test to check if HTTP/2 is supported by my web application, it says "Yeah! xxxxx supports HTTP/2.0"

But when I use Chrome or Lighthouse (to test) it tells me content is being served over HTTP/1.1

Comment: I just tested this on my Chrome 63 with IIS10 on 2016, it results in HTTP 2 traffic. Start with a very basic site/page and see whether that works? open `chrome://net-internals/#http2` in a new tab to check.